# AsyncFileUpload event not being triggered

Tags: asp.net, events, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have the following cod:

```
<asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="asyncUploader" runat="server" ThrobberID="myThrobber" BackColor="#ff99cc"/><br /><br />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="debug"></asp:Label>
```

The c# file looks loke this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        asyncUploader.UploadedComplete += new EventHandler<AsyncFileUploadEventArgs>(uploadComplete);
 }

 protected void uploadComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
 {
        debug.Text += "y";
        if (asyncUploader.HasFile == true)
        {
            debug.Text += "x";
        }
 }
```

The text in the label doesn't change when I select a file to upload or when it finishes downloading. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The label text will is actually changing but because of the AsyncFileUpload *postback* it is resetting each time the uploadComplete method is called. So a better way would be using javascript to change the label text.

You can AsyncFileUpload's `OnClientUploadComplete` event to accomplish this.

Add the `OnClientUploadComplete` event to your AsyncFileUpload markup like this:

```
<asp:AsyncFileUpload OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" ID="asyncUploader" runat="server" ThrobberID="myThrobber" BackColor="#ff99cc"/><br /><br />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="debug"></asp:Label>
```

Then add the `uploadComplete` function in markup:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
            //First, change the label text
            document.getElementById("<%= debug.ClientID %>").innerHTML += "y";
            //Check if the upload has files or not
            if (document.getElementById("asyncUploader").value != "") {
                //It has files, change the label text
                document.getElementById("<%= debug.ClientID %>").innerHTML += "x";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

This way you don't need to do anything in code-behind, all will be done in javascript.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The purpose of the text is only for debug purposes. That's why is named "debug". I was just wondering if there's a way to call the method and the data that I alter to persist.

Comment: ah I see I thought the problem was just that you need to change the label text after the upload complete. can you tell me exactly what you're trying to achieve so that I could help?

Comment: I am trying to have a button appear and disappear when the file is uploaded, and if a file is uploaded and you click the button, the file gets unloaded and the button dissapears